# Induce re-render from other component React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to induce a re-render from another component, avoiding the "triggering component" to re-render.

```
const App = () => {

    const [isPopUpActive, setIsPopUpActive] = useState(false)

    const popUpOnOff = () => {
        if(isPopUpActive)
            setIsPopUpActive(false)
        else
            setIsPopUpActive(true)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <SomeComponent
                trigger={popUpOnOff}
            />
            <PopUpComponent
                isActive={isPopUpActive}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I thought wrapping the `SomeComponent` with `React.memo` and changing a prop in the `PopUpComponent` would do it, but calling the `trigger` function in the `SomeComponent` re-renders everything. Is there a way to avoid the first component to re-render?

Answer (score 2):

The identity of the `popUpOnOff` function changes on each render, so the memoized component can't do anything.

You will need to memoize that callback instead, making it depend on the data it uses:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [isPopUpActive, setIsPopUpActive] = useState(false);

  const popUpOnOff = useCallback(() => {
    setIsPopUpActive(!isPopUpActive);
  }, [isPopUpActive, setIsPopUpActive]);

  return (
    <div>
      <SomeComponent trigger={popUpOnOff} />
      <PopUpComponent isActive={isPopUpActive} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: the next state is calculated based on the current state. You should use an updater function instead of relying on closures

Comment: and that's not how `useMemo` works. Maybe you wanted `useCallback`?

Comment: @marzelin Ah, yeah, good point. (Quoth the docs, though: `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)` – I was almost there :) )

Comment: this is not working, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I think the only solution to this is to use a class component and implement a shouldComponentUpdate method.

Comment: I stringifyed the method and compared it and it works.